# Predicting projectile trajectory based on only positional data

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, projectile, simulations, drag

Sorry if this is a stupid question, as a CS major I'm not as well versed in physics as I would like to be. For a computer simulation, I am trying to predict a trajectory of a ballistic missile based only on $x, y, z$ position readings (i.e. data you would expect from a radar-like system).

So far, I have looked into a decent amount of tutorials, but they mostly revolve around working with a known angle of takeoff, and then calculating the full trajectory accordingly. What I want to do is to find the position function of the missile based on multiple $(x, y, z)$ readings alone.

My best guess would be to integrate the speed vector (thus the derivative of the position) to get its position function for each axis, but I am unsure how this would work in a practical sense.

In the (simplified) 2D example, the blue line is what I want to know, i.e. the parabolic future trajectory of the missile, whereas the white dots are known positions over the last $t$ seconds.

Would love to get some pointers on where to start with this!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Split the velocity into two components

$v_x$ and $v_y$

$v_x$ can be found from the $x$ position of the last data point, e.g. 4/5 or about 0.8m/s on your diagram.

Then the future $x$ position is $x = v_x \times t$

For $y$ also using the last data point, find $v_y$ by solving

$$y = v_y t - 0.5\times9.8\times t^2$$

$t$ would be 5 and $y$ about 4 again from your diagram.

The for future $y$ co-ordinate, use the same equation above, with different values of $t$.

If you don't know the time of launch, adapt the method above using the first and last data points - i.e. $t$ becomes $4$ and look at the change in the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates between those two data points.

All the best with it.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your thorough explanation. Splitting up the velocities is really helpful. However, I did run into an issue with the y velocity. I solved the equation for y = 4 and t = 5, resulting in a y velocity of 25.3. When I plug in t=5, the outcome is 4, as desired. However, when I plug in t = 4 or t = 6, things seem to go wrong. For example, at t=6, the predicted y is -24.6! I'm sure I'm missing something here and would appreciate any help! Calculation: https://imgur.com/a/JT7K30a

Comment: @ Frans   I used the squares to try and make the method clear, but you would need realistic time and $y$ values, maybe the same for $x$.  What does each square represent, in the $x$ and $y$ direction, and what are the time intervals between data points?

Comment: Edit: I should probably have called the x-axis 't' for time instead of 'x'. The y-axis would then represent the height in meters of the projectile for a given t time in seconds. The trajectory prediction code I'll be writing will be hooked up to a (simulated) radar system that reports back the (x,y) position data of a simulated projectile that is affected by simulated gravitation pull. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ Frans, yes, if the projectile reaches the top in about 5 seconds, then if the data points are one second apart, if we take the $y$ squares as 30m each, the method should work, using the same long equation (with y=120), gives $v_y$ as 48.5 and then when t=6, it's realistic

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I just plotted the equation using the 30cm per square measurement and it's a parabolic function as I expected. I suppose my previous attempt failed because I used nonsense x and y values. Thanks for the help John!

Comment: @ Frans  Glad it's ok now.  all the best